# Is there a way to argue that this differential equation is bounded by a universal constant $K$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

Suppose $p>1$ with $x_1(0),x_2(0)>0$ and $x_1(t),x_2(t)>0$ for all $t$. In this problem, $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ are the solutions to two coupled ODEs.

I would like to argue that $$x_1(t)^p+c_{12}x_1(t)^px_2(t)^2+x_2(t)^p+c_{21}x_2(t)^px_1(t)^2-x_1(t)^{p+2}-x_2(t)^{p+2} \leq K$$

Here $K$ is some constant, and $c_{21},c_{12}$ are constants as well. If the $c_{ij} < 0$, clearly $K$ exists. But what if they're both positive or one positive and one negative? Is it still true or do I need an additional condition such as $c_{12} < 1$ which should allow the leading term of degree $p+2$ to dominate?

Comment: What is the differential equation? Or, does your inequality have nothing to do with differential equations?

Comment: @mickep $dx_1 = x_1(1-x_1^2-x_2^2)+c_{12}x_1x_2^2 dt$ and 
$dx_2 = x_2(1-x_1^2-x_2^2)+c_{21}x_2x_1^2 dt$

Comment: @mickep The inequality is a result of using these differential equations, but this inequality really doesn't have too much bearing on what the diff eqs are